# Take screenshot with Kif

Tags: iphone, ios, screenshot, kif-framework

I want to take a screenshot in Kif.  I saw [here](https://github.com/square/KIF/blob/master/Classes/KIFTestController.m#L437) in a private class in the kif project that it is possible, but I am having a hard time trying to convert it to a step.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing with this for a bit I added this to my `KIFTestStep.m`

```
 + (id)stepToTakeScreenShotwithName:(NSString *)name;
 {
     NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take a screenshot saved by the name %@", name];

     return [self stepWithDescription:description executionBlock:^(KIFTestStep *step, NSError **error) {

         NSString *outputPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/ScreenShots", NSUserName()];

         NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
         if (windows.count == 0) {
             return KIFTestStepResultFailure;
         }

         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([[windows objectAtIndex:0] bounds].size);
         for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
             [window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
         }
         UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

         NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
         NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];

         outputPath = [outputPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
         outputPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"]];
         outputPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingString:[timeStampObj stringValue]];
         outputPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
         [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:outputPath atomically:YES];

         return KIFTestStepResultSuccess;
    }];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This was added in KIF 3.0.4.  See [here](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/commit/80823725bf46ffb626342e3de50d85d57d567edc).